# MATLAB function open works in workspace, but not in function

Tags: string, matlab, function, command-window

I am trying to create a video file with MATLAB. Here is my function:

```
function [vidObj] = createVideo(frames, frameRate, filename)

%Create video object
num_frames = size(frames,2);
vidObj = VideoWriter(filename);
vidObj.Quality = 100;
vidObj = frameRate;
open(vidObj);

%some more stuff...
```

The issue is that MATLAB always gives me an error at the call to open(vidObj) saying

```
Error using open (line 69)
NAME must contain a single string.
```

My string is simple...just 'test_video.avi'. But it's not working. I also tried going in the function and replacing 'filename' with literal strings.

What is strange is that when I just type the commands into the command window, it works fine. Why? And how can I make this work in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may be overwriting your video object, `vidObj`, with the line `vidObj = frameRate;`.

Try replacing with `vidObj.FrameRate = frameRate;`.